# Why ooyala's player.playMovie() method does'nt work?

Tags: ooyala

Why does ooyala's methods like play,pause, get current... wont work from console or from code.
i get:

TypeError: Object # has no method 'playMovie'

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but it sounds like you are still using our V2 player (please try to upgrade) and haven't declared a callback in the url params for player.js.  Without it, we will not initialize any JS apis.

See http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/api/player_api_js.html for more details.

Comment: Note: That link to support.ooyala.com 404s. I think you're looking for this one: http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/book_api_player.html